# Simple TextFormField validator, but not return anything

Tags: flutter

I have a question on how to use validator. I cannot see where I got it wrong. The code I wrote is, when click a button, it pops up a dialog and ask user to input a name.

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => Dialog(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                key: _formKey,
                controller: roomController,
                validator: (String value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please create name';
                    } else if (NameList.contains(value)) {
                      return 'Existed';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Create'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  child: Text('Create'),
),
```

The codes work fine, do everything I intended to, except the validator part.
Did I miss anything here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check for the validation inside onPress Button like this

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => Dialog(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                key: _formKey,
                controller: roomController,
                validator: (String value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please create name';
                    } else if (NameList.contains(value)) {
                      return 'Existed';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
           if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
           return //someting
                     }
              },
                child: Text('Create'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  child: Text('Create'),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two option in order to make the validation works, your code is correct by you are not triggering the validation:

1. By calling

```
if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {}
```

this will trigger the validation,

2. Old solution is by using `autovalidate:true` parameter to `Form` (deprecated after 1.19). now you need to use `AutovalidateMode` and you have some options like `onUserInteraction` and `always` and `disabled`. Yu can check the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutovalidateMode-class.html) for further information.

The first one can be used if you need the validation when the user click on button, and the second one is dynamic depending on the parameter you have passed to the ```Form```